# Can a Jenkins master be restarted without affecting agents?

Tags: jenkins

I was wondering if a Jenkins master can be restarted without affect the agents.  Currently, we're planning on using safeExit to stop the master.  Thanks

Comment: It has been a few years since I used Jenkins regularly.  However, 5 years ago the answer was "no".  When Jenkins rebooted it reallocated executors.  However, just try it!  Allocate a bunch of jobs doing say "sleep 60000" and then reboot the Jenkins.  I suspect everything will be gone.  I memory is less clear if the "sleep" processes will still be running in the slaves.  I think the answer is also "no", but a test will prove it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While restarting master, slaves will try to connect to master and 'pause' jobs.

You can see it in jobs output after master will be back online.

Comment: OK, so whilte the master is restarting, the slaves will pause their jobs, and presumably, after the master is back up again, the slaves will continue their existing jobs?